# Discussion regarding frequent use of 'Mod powers' by Diamond Moderators to close harmless questions

Tags: discussion, moderation

Today I noticed that two question were put on hold by Diamond Moderators using their 'Mod power'

[Why didn't the Avengers use the Mind stone to change the minds of the Black Order or Thanos?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89913/why-didnt-the-avengers-use-the-mind-stone-to-change-the-minds-of-the-black-orde) was put on hold by 1 normal user and then by a Diamond Moderator.

[which among the 17 powers will Jack Jack retain when he becomes adult?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89919/which-among-the-17-powers-will-jack-jack-retain-when-he-becomes-adult)  was put on hold by 2 normal users and then by a different Diamond Moderator.

The 1st question was reopened quickly while the second is on hold. So Mods took 50% correct decisions today. Instead they could have let the users decide & keep their correct decision making report sheet better.

A diamond moderator should step in and use his mod powers on controversial/abusive/spam questions or answers but not for harmless questions and answers which can be dealt by the community. It takes 5 users to put a question on hold but a Diamond Moderator can do that on his own. If done too frequently, it borders on mod-abuse.

What does the community & the moderators themselves think about this? Should Diamond Mod powers be used in special circumstances only (for harmless questions)?

Comment: If it's off topic then why moderators should hold there hands? Mod are not only for handling controversial/abusive/spam but also they should close posts when they are off topic.

Comment: As I mentioned, they can use normal power to vote & wait for 4 more to agree. Moderaters can't be all knowing beings & their decisions are not 100% correct.

Comment: Mod's vote is binding for closing and after your edit it's already getting reopen. In its first state it was way opinion based when closed, I am still not convinced but community can decide.

Comment: @KharoBangdo mod's can't use regular close votes.

Comment: I am not arguing that. I am arguing about mod power in innocuous question

Comment: I don't see how either version of the question is POB, but instead of having this discussion framed around a single question, this might serve a broader discussion of whether mods should use these powers so liberally. Yes, questions can be reopened again, but the initial closure will tank the chances of hitting HNQ and/or getting some good exposure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma is what JAD is saying correct?. If is it, then I didn't know about it. I thought you only activate mod powers when needed.

Comment: But yes, although unintentional on my part asking the question, we should discuss mod powers being used so frequently

Comment: The point is, the question *wasn't* innocuous. It was an entirely speculative "why didn't the characters do what I would have done?" question. You can't just call your question "innocuous" and free it from any proper judgement by the site's standards. Moderators close questions that aren't appropriate for the site, that's what they do. The question *does* seem to have improved a little, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson don't try to misunderstand my question. Innocuous here means harmless. Primarily opinion based questions are harmless. They must be closed as such but by users. It's is ones primary opinion to close opinion based questions. If 5 people agree on an opinion, it is good enough to be accepted by the community. A harmless question is rude/abusive/spam/trolling/blatantly off topic & mods must move in immediately to close without relying on other 4 opinion. I can debate semantics if you want

Comment: @KharoBangdo See [this declined feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-close-open-vote)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I don't see how that is different from any other ["Why didn't?" question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+didn%27t) on this site.

Comment: @KharoBangdo .... what JAD says is correct, mods can't "vote to close" they can only close.  This is why I sometimes hesitate to close (or reopen) because its so final and let the community decide on "grey area" issues.

Comment: Mods & users, I changed the tone of the question from accusatory to discussiony. I hope you participate to give some clarity regarding this.

Comment: *"The 1st question was reopened quickly while the second is on hold. So Mods took 50% correct decisions today."* - That's quite a misinterpretation (and mis*representation*, too) of what happened and how SE works. If a question gets closed and later gets reopened *after a considerable improvement* that doesn't mean closing the question was somehow "incorrect", it means closing the question actually did what it was supposed to do, put the question on hold until it gets improved into validity. The question didn't just get reopened after everyone realized their mistake, but after it was improved.

Comment: Maybe we should rather enlighten that user on how to flesh out his questions a little more sufficiently. Granted, you could blame the moderators and the rest of the community for not being a little more proactive in this regard.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson please. Understand my intent. The community could do that on its own. Why don't the mods wait a bit for community to reach to that decision. Because waiting a bit would do no harm. And to address your question about improvement, When I got to the question, it had 2 reopen votes. I would have voted to reopen as it is. I improved the question so that it can get some upvotes.

Comment: At the end of the day, though, as much as trying to discuss this issue is a noble goal, it ultimately comes down to what *you* (or everyone else) actually consider a "harmless" question in contrast to a "special circumstance". Without some clear consensus on what is what, this really leads nowhere. In fact I *totally agree that moderators shouldn't do anything to harmless questions*, but that doesn't help if we're at odds about what a "harmless" question is.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I will answer my thoughts on this in detail. Meanwhile, why don't you flesh out a detailed answer so that I know your viewpoint clearly

Comment: @KharoBangdo I wait for community consensus very often actually on a variety of question where I'm not sure if it should be closed or not. Of course there's no way for me to show you since, well, I didn't do anything to those questions. I do this exactly because I'm myself unsure about it and don't want to take the decision away from the community. When I see an entirely inappropriate question, though, I'd rather not wait. There's clear areas where we don't really need to educate the community into helping itself, since it's a somewhat established site already.

Comment: Frankly, I don't really know how to answer this question yet and I'm not entirely sure I'm able to in its current form, let alone that it deserves an actual answer yet. It still seems to suffer from quite a few problems in its very premise. Arguing about the specific questions doesn't seem your goal here and as said, the general discussion seems both a little oddly premised and unspecified. Besides that, we wouldn't want the moderators to act too fast on this before the community gets their voice, eh? ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yes ok. It you have problem with my interpretation of harmful & harmless, you just present your version of harmful & harmless.in the answer. And I am not targeting you specifically. Ankit Sharma also did same thing today

Comment: See, I don't *have* a version. If we all had a version of "harmfull" that we could write down on paper, life would be a ton easier. The closest definition I have is "questions that should clearly be put on hold", but that's as helpful as nothing. If we're not arguing about the specific questions (and I agree that might be futile), then that's the most accurate definition we can reach. But I'll see if this question garners some traction that makes it worthwhile to answer. I know you're not targeting me specifically, though, don't worry.

Answer (score 5):

> The 1st question was reopened quickly while the second is on hold. So Mods took 50% correct decisions today.

The second statement in no way follows from the first. The first question seems to have been re-opened ***after it was edited***. The mod who closed it initially then would seem to have made the correct decision to place the question **on hold** pending the edit that made that question more appropriate. That suggests that mods made 100% correct decisions in these cases.

(emphasis added below)

> A diamond moderator should step in ... but not for *harmless* questions and answers which can be dealt by the community.

There is no SE or M&TV.SE concept of "harmless" or "harmful" in terms of how content should be treated by mods or by the rest of the community. This is a concept you have invented for this meta question. A better way to propose a distinction here would be to explicitly suggest it, such as a meta question along the lines of "*Should off-topic and opinion based questions be treated differently from spam/abusive/vulgar questions?*" Then inside that meta question, you could propose to call the former type "harmless" and the latter type "harmful". Short of something like that, there's no reason why I or any other user should consider a spam question any more harmful to the SE model than an opinion based question.

---

Overall, I think we should all keep in mind the following:

### Questions are put *On Hold*, not "closed" by votes and mods

On hold means, "we are not allowing answers to this question until the question itself has been made better and up to the standards of the site". It does **not** mean "we are permanently removing this question from consideration".

It is totally understandable to *feel* that an on hold question has been completely and permanently rejected from the site, but ***it's just not the case***. On hold questions are paused and awaiting edits to address problems. That's exactly what happened with one of your example questions, and it shows the system working exactly as it is intended to work.

---

Edit based on a comment:

> The community could do that on its own. Why don't the mods wait a bit for community to reach to that decision.

This seems to suggest that the mods and the community are two different entities that should have separate roles and duties on the site. **The mods are a part of the community**, which is why it's called "*community moderated*". To say mods should do one thing and the community do another thing doesn't make a lot of sense. Remember, if five users with enough rep vote to re-open a question put on hold by a mod, then the question is reopened. So the mods don't have the power to single-handedly shut out the rest of the community, in most cases.

Comment: Just stating that when I got to the question, there were no edits to the question & 2 reopen votes. I would have reopened it as it is. I edited it because I thought more context would gather upvotes to the question. If the community agrees that my edits made the question from primarily opinion based to factual  then although I wouldn't agree with that decision but I would accept it.

Comment: I think you have understood "community moderated" backwards. It means community at large participates in moderation in addition to Mods unlike sites like Reddit which are "moderator moderated" where only mods do moderation & the community has no moderation power

Comment: You quoted a part of the question & edited out the part where I make a clear distinction between what is harmful & what is harmless. So the quote is lacking context. I urge you to add my full quote & not part of it.